# How to Make Smooth Bevel Curve Without Extra Crease?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, bevel

I want to make something like a curve-shape pipe,
so I use curve (I make an edge and convert it to curve because I need it like that in original work) and bevel it with *bevel>object> beziercircle* and it looks like that:
[image]

After that I convert it to mesh, and do bevel of the angle edge loop in the middle
[image]

But it look like that:
[image]

So how can I make it even and smooth without these crease that indicated by red arrows?
I add subdivision modifier and auto-smooth but it still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe put an additional edge loop close to it, it should attenuate the problem:

[image]

If you ever want an alternative that works (but the whole profile is different so it may not be what you want):

Create your pipe with a series of vertices, when you want to curve an angle, bevel the vertex:

[image]

[image]

Convert to curve, go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry*, and bevel:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I like simple solutions, so here's my take on the problem

1.Enable the [*Add Mesh: Extra Objects*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/add_mesh/mesh_extra_objects.html#add-mesh-extra-objects) add-on in preferences if not already enabled (it is bundled with Blender by default)

2.<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *>mesh>Pipe Joints> Pipe Elbow*

3.In the redo panel (<kbd>F9</kbd> in default 2.8x keymap) change the angle as desired

4.Add [Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#subdivision-surface-modifier)

### [image]

*Note, if curves are an absolute necessity at some point after this, you can always convert this mesh (or a copy of it) to a curve.*

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd start with a cylinder, select the vertices round one end and then use the Spin tool to extrude round the cursor. Details From the [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/spin.html) or a  [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcESDOixsj0).